# Is there a typo in this modified Lennard-Jones potential?

Tags: classical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

The [standard 12-6 Lennard Jones potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) is given by

$$U(r_ij) = 4\epsilon\left[ \left(\frac{\sigma_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac{\sigma_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\right)^{6} \right]$$

where $\epsilon$ and $\sigma$ are the parameters.

I am reading a [paper (Pohorille, A.; Jarzynski, C.; Chipot, C. *J. Phys. Chem. B* **2010**, *114*, 10235-10253)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp102971x), and my mind is very cloudy right now.  In the paper, in **equation (65)** on page 15 (p. 10249), the authors define a so-called soft-core potential by modifying the original Lennard-Jones potential using parameters $\lambda$ and $\alpha$:

$$U(r_{ij}; \lambda) = 4\epsilon\left(1-\lambda\right)^{n}\left\{ \frac{1}{\left[\alpha\lambda^{2}+\left(\frac{\sigma_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\right)^{6}\right]^{2}}-\frac{1}{\alpha\lambda^{2}+\left(\frac{\sigma_{ij}}{r_{ij}}\right)^{6}}\right\} $$

Then the paper says:

> ... the original Lennard-Jones potential is fully recovered at
>   $\lambda = 0$.

But *I think* that if I plug $\lambda = 0$ into the equation above, I get:

$$U(r_ij) = 4\epsilon\left[ \left(\frac{r_{ij}}{\sigma_{ij}}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac{r_{ij}}{\sigma_{ij}}\right)^{6} \right]$$

which is  not the original Lennard-Jones potential.

Is there something wrong with my reasoning, or is there a typo in the paper?

Answer (score 5):

You are right, there is most likely a typo in the paper. Presumably they mean
$$U(r_{ij}; \lambda) = 4\epsilon\left(1-\lambda\right)^{n}\left\{ \frac{1}{\left[\alpha\lambda^{2}+\left(\frac{r_{ij}}{\sigma_{ij}}\right)^{6}\right]^{2}}-\frac{1}{\alpha\lambda^{2}+\left(\frac{r_{ij}}{\sigma_{ij}}\right)^{6}}\right\}. $$
This is what's given in their reference ([*Chem. Phys. Lett.* **222** no. 6, pp. 529-539 (2010)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614%2894%2900397-1), equation 7, p. 532) except for a reparametrization $\lambda\leftrightarrow(1-\lambda)$.